# Compiling external firmware into kernel with CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE - Make failing with "No rule to make target"

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, kbuild, kconfig

I have some pre-compiled firmware blobs, including `foo.bin`, that I'd like to have included in the kernel binary that I'm compiling so it can be accessed in early boot. I've included "foo.bin" in `CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE`, but when I set `CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE_DIR` to the directory (`/my/absolute/path/to/dir`) holding my blobs, I get:

```
make[9]: *** No rule to make target '/my/absolute/path/to/dir/foo.bin', needed by 'drivers/base/firmware_loader/builtin/foo.bin.gen.o'.  Stop.
```

`drivers/base/firmware_loader/builtin/Makefile` implies that `CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE_DIR` can take an absolute path (I assume all of this is referring to paths on the host/build machine) which leads me to believe that the firmware blobs don't need to live in the kernel source tree.

How can I get Make to accept my file(s)? Do I need to do something in the directory with `foo.bin`? Does that directory have to be in the kernel source tree? Any advice appreciated!

(As a first shot in the dark at a fix, I added a dummy Makefile in `/my/absolute/path/to/dir` that has a dummy rule for my file:

```
foo.bin:
    @:
```

But that (pretty expectedly) didn't work)

Comment: Are you sure `/my/absolute/path/to/dir/foo.bin` exists? What make tells you is that it could not find it, so it tried to create it but has no clue how to do this. Double-check that it's really there, that there are no spelling errors in your paths (when checking that copy-paste the path from the error message), that it's not a dangling symlink...